# Calling a method from another view in objective-c. (iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, methods, messaging

I am currently creating a multi-view game on the iPhone platform.  I have my main view start to play some background music upon loading.  I then go to another view and start the game.  I am trying to get the background music from the original view to stop once I start the game.  I am having trouble getting the stop playing music message to my original view.  Here is the relevant info:

The main view where the sound is played from is just a subView of the programViewController class called *viewController.  The heading is in the programAppDelegate class.

The sound is done using the AVAudioPlayer class and plays fine when the program starts up and when I navigate to other subviews that are added on by going through the menu system.

In the view that I want to start the game, I attempt to call the instance of the class to turn of the player but anytime I use this format of code:

```
[viewController #######];
```

It gives a build error of "**viewController undeclared**" no matter what I put after the "viewController" in the message.I have attempted to import the programAppDelegate.h file but it still gives the same error.

I realize this might be a simple misunderstanding of the objective-c language but I cannot find any info on this issue.  I am a recent convert from Java so I am trying to wrap my head around everything.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

"**viewController undeclared**" means the variable `viewController` cannot be found. The message you send to is irrelevant. Make sure `viewController` exists in that scope first.

(Do you mean `self.viewController`?)

Comment: I know I can't get the message to viewController.  That is why I put the hashes afterwards.  I just don't know how to make it in scope.  I am in another view "secondViewController" class and need to call a method to the object in the "viewController" class but can't seem to be able to figure out how to do that.